# What does the first line "Total" indicate while executing the ls -l command in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Here I see the total value is equal to 60. What exactly does the total indicate?

```
tanaysuthar@ubuntu:~$ ls -l
total 60
drwxr -xr -x 2 tanaysuthar tanaysuthar 4096 Nov 14 13:05 Desktop
drwxr -xr -x 3 tanaysuthar tanaysuthar 4096 Dec 10 11:14 Documents
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the total number of disk blocks taken up by directory.

Comment: Note that it is 512 byte blocks unless the `-k` option is used (whereupon it becomes 1024 byte or 1 KiB blocks).  See the POSIX specification for [`ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).

Comment: Okay... So here Block size is equal to 512 bytes..